# ¿Por que me da error al ejecutar TorghostNG?

Tags: python, android

Instale TorghostNG en mi celular pero al momento de ejecutarlo me manda este error, me podrían ayudar a solucionarlo o al menos explicarme que lo causa...

```
[+] Start connecting to Tor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torghostng.py", line 548, in <module>
    start_connecting()
  File "torghostng.py", line 298, in start_connectig
    IF DISABLE_IPv6 == open(Sysct1).read():
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] no such file or directory:
```

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Este error... 
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] no such file or directory:
y no se termina de ejecutar la aplicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido,

No conozco el programa pero navegando a través del código desde su página en github (fuente: https://github.com/GitHackTools/TorghostNG/blob/master/torghostng.py) me atrevería a concluir una serie de cosas, tirando de la traza del error:

**Línea 298**

```
if DISABLE_IPv6 == open(Sysctl).read():
```

Esa sentencia condicional **if** intenta abrir el archivo (veáse *open* https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open ) cuya dirección se almacena en el valor de la variable *Sysctl*. Haciendo una búsqueda en el código vemos que dicha variable se define y se le asigna un valor en la línea **55**

**Línea 55**

```
Sysctl = '/etc/sysctl.conf'
```

Por consiguiente dicha función está intentando abrir ese archivo y me atrevería a decir que dicho archivo no existe en dicho directorio. Compruebalo en tu sistema operativo.

Adicionalmente te paso el README del programa donde puedes ver los OS compatibles:
https://github.com/GitHackTools/TorghostNG/blob/master/README.md

Saludos